# How to define an interface in Kotlin that uses @DrawableRes annotations?

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to create an interface to define a group of `drawables` needed for a mic state, something like:

```
interface MicrophoneState {
    val iconResource: Int
    val backgroundResource: Int
}
```

since it should be a resource id I wanted to decorated it with `@DrawableRes` but I get an error when I do that:

> This annotation is not applicable to target 'member property without backing field or delegate'

Is there a way to fix that problem? all the question I have found are about classes but not interfaces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it's a state use of data class is ideal

```
data class MicrophoneState (
    @DrawableRes val iconResource: Int,
    @DrawableRes val backgroundResource: Int
)
```

or if you want to use interface

```
interface MicrophoneState {
    @DrawableRes fun iconResource(): Int
    @DrawableRes fun backgroundResource(): Int
}
```

Any one will work.

Update :
I think you are looking for this exactly :

```
interface MicrophoneState {
    @get:DrawableRes val iconResource:Int
    @get:DrawableRes val backgroundResource:Int
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need an interface as apparently you're trying to build a model to store data?

```
class HelloWorldClass (@DrawableRes val value1: Int, @DrawableRes val value2: Int)
```

(you can as well go with data class)

Interface is a contract for something:

```
interface HelloWorldInterface {
    fun myMethod(@DrawableRes value: Int)
}
```